# Readings on writing high-performance server in Java

Tags: java, performance, c10k

Could anyone please introduce books/papers/articles that I should read If I want to write a high-performance RPC server in Java, which handles large number of concurrent connections(C10K or over), is fault-tolerant, can be scaled out, and maintains high throughput? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A few years ago Ebay reimplemented their platform in Java and there are a few white papers and presentations floating around that describe it. Here are some:

- http://www.sun.com/2003-0624/feature/index.html
- http://www.infoq.com/presentations/shoup-ebay-architectural-principles
- http://www.infoq.com/articles/ebay-scalability-best-practices

Supposedly there is a link to a relevant white paper somewhere on this site, though I haven't found it yet:
  http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to read about the LMAX architecture, they are doing more than 100k transactions per second on a Java system.

- [Martin Fowler - The LMAX Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html)
- [InfoQ - LMAX - How to Do 100K TPS at Less than 1ms Latency](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/LMAX)